# using alter command in tsql which contains default caluse

Tags: t-sql

I want to add a column to a table using alter Command which contains defalut clause, and the older rows which are existing in the table should be populated automatically to the default value.

thanks n regards

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ADD NewColumn VARCHAR(20) 
  CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable_NewColumn DEFAULT('ABC-123') WITH VALUES
```

The `CONSTRAINT DF_YourTable_NewColumn DEFAULT('ABC-123')` defines a named default constraint (explicitly named, so you could drop it, if needed) and the `WITH VALUES` indicates the columns should be filled with the default value.